# How do I compare pressed Key values in keyDown event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, keydown

I am trying to something very trivial here but somehow cant get my head around it.. I am handling KeyDown event of telerik grid in wpf.

There is want to check if key pressed was a number or decimal, so for that I do..

```
If ((e.Key >= Keys.D0 AndAlso e.Key <= Keys.D9) OrElse
    (e.Key >= Keys.NumPad0 AndAlso e.Key <= Keys.NumPad9) OrElse
    e.Key = Keys.Decimal) Then

        e.Handled = False
Else
        e.Handled = True
End If
```

but the above if never satisfies.. for instance if I press D4

these are the computed values in if

```
Dim one = e.Key >= Keys.D0 -> False
Dim two = e.Key <= Keys.D9 -> True
Dim three = e.Key >= Keys.NumPad0 -> False
Dim four = e.Key <= Keys.NumPad9 -> True
Dim five = e.Key = Keys.Decimal -> False
```

Why is D4 less than D9 comes true but not greater than D0 ?

how can I simple compare pressed key with range of key values?

I hope I  have explained as much as I could but in case you need any clarification please ask..

thanks

Comment: Are you comparing like with like?  is `e.Key` actually from the [`Keys` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or is it from the [`Key` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  `D4` (and the other digits) have different values in each and would explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: You can very well come and kick me for this ... thanks a ton man... dunno how could I miss that .... probably Dim two = e.Key <= Keys.D9 -> coming out true confused me ..

Comment: please feel free to move it to ans and I will mark it...

Comment: why down vote it man, its vb compiler not raises errors lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you comparing like with like?  Note that (for whatever reason), .NET has (at least) two different Key enumerations.  It looks like you're comparing against the  [`Keys` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from Windows.Forms, but you may need to instead compare against the [`Key` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from System.Windows.Input.

The members of each Enum have different values, so would explain the behaviour you're seeing if you are using the wrong one.

Comment: Interestingly, in C# you get a compiler error if you try to compare them, but not in VB.

Comment: ah ... that's odd.. CLR it is :)